# Can I put a right inswing front door with a left outswing screen

Tags: doors, exterior

Can I put a right hand swing door (Exterior) with a left out swing screen door??

Comment: This is the ideal set-up for every person who is right-handed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can as long as there is a floor or landing on either side. There cannot be any steps at either door, where the door can swing over them.

Comment: Thanks. So my front door can be a right inswing and I can put a screen /glass door, as long as there is a landing on both sides, with a left outswing. This wont look stupid?? Our front door will go out to a porch with limited space on the one side. I didn't want to walk out the door and have to walk past the screen then around

Comment: I have seen doors with that arrangement you mention, I have seen them with the doors set so both were left hand or right hand. Your arrangement will be feel more natural to walk through. I can't tell you all the details about how the limited space will work with it since I have not seen how it is laid out. What I do know, is that the other way in my opinion feels like I am square dancing going through, using one hand to open the first, then the other hand to open the second door.